rolling difference between a selected base code compared to other code in R
I have a code where there is a scenario (sc column) and a code name (cd column). I want to calculate the difference between all scenarios to the first one (so scenario 2-1, 3-1, etc. I have multiple more scenarios...). Is there a quick way to code which scenario will be compared, for example, if I now the scenario from which all the other are compared is now scenario 2, it would be 1-2, 3-2, etc.?
But I also want to make sure that between scenarios, I subtract only the same code names (cd) so (sc1.cd1 - sc2.cd1),  (sc1.cd2 - sc2.cd2), etc.
I also want the percentage difference between the sc 1 compared to the other scenarios for each code.
Right now, my code assumes that when I compare the scenarios, the cd are in the same order. Would there be a way to compare the scenarios and code together rather than using a subset of the data?
set.seed(123456)
vals = as.vector(mapply(FUN = rpois, n = 10, lambda = c(5, 10, 100)))
df.test = data.frame(cd = rep(1:10,3), sc = rep(1:3, each =10 ), vals)

# New empty column 
df.test$delta = NA

# Subset each scenarios and subtract for the first scenario
df.test[df.test$sc ==1,'delta'] = df.test[df.test$sc ==1,'vals']-df.test[df.test$sc ==1,'vals']
df.test[df.test$sc ==2,'delta'] = df.test[df.test$sc ==2,'vals']-df.test[df.test$sc ==1,'vals']
df.test[df.test$sc ==3,'delta'] = df.test[df.test$sc ==3,'vals']-df.test[df.test$sc ==1,'vals']

# Get difference
df.test$diff = abs(abs(df.test$delta) - df.test$vals)

# Calculate percentage
df.test$delta.perc = abs(df.test$delta) / df.test$diff +1
df.test$diff * df.test$delta.perc

# Percentage increase
df.test$delta.perc.increase = df.test$delta.perc *100


The problem is that you've hardcoded the differences between scenarios while assuming cd values will align perfectly, which makes changing the base scenario not quite cumbersome, but definitely a hassle.
We can use dplyr to handle the grouping and calculations, this way we can set any base scenario dynamically, like 1, 2, or whatever you want. We will also make sure that the differences are calculated only between matching cd values, so there are no assumptions.
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123456)
vals <- as.vector(mapply(FUN = rpois, n = 10, lambda = c(5, 10, 100)))
df_test <- data.frame(cd = rep(1:10, 3), sc = rep(1:3, each = 10), vals)

base_scenario <- 1

df_test <- df_test %>%
  group_by(cd) %>%
  mutate(
    base_vals = vals[sc == base_scenario],
    delta = vals - base_vals,
    delta_perc = ifelse(base_vals != 0, delta / base_vals * 100, NA)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

print(df_test)

this way you can set the base_scenario to whatever value you want and it updates automagically, and by grouping by cd we ensure that the delta's are individually calculated for each cd, so you get sc1.cd1 - sc2.cd2 rather than just subtracting rows in order. I also added the ifelse to prevent any div/0 errors when the base value is 0.
Doing it this way lets you change the base_scenario to any value and it will change for it—so you'll get 1-2, 3-2, etc., when the base is set to 2.
If I've not explained anything well enough, feel free to leave a question in the replies :)

You could sapply the subtraction over the unique(sc). Using transform you don't need to write df.test$ all the time.
> df.test |> 
+   transform(delta=sapply(unique(sc), FUN=\(x) {
+     vals[sc == x] - vals[sc == 1]
+   }) |> as.vector()) |> 
+   transform(dif=abs(delta - vals)) |> 
+   transform(delta.perc=abs(delta)/dif + 1) |> 
+   transform(delta.perc.increase=delta.perc*100)
   cd sc vals delta dif delta.perc delta.perc.increase
1   1  1    7     0   7   1.000000            100.0000
2   2  1    6     0   6   1.000000            100.0000
3   3  1    4     0   4   1.000000            100.0000
4   4  1    4     0   4   1.000000            100.0000
5   5  1    4     0   4   1.000000            100.0000
6   6  1    3     0   3   1.000000            100.0000
7   7  1    5     0   5   1.000000            100.0000
8   8  1    2     0   2   1.000000            100.0000
9   9  1   11     0  11   1.000000            100.0000
10 10  1    3     0   3   1.000000            100.0000
11  1  2   12     5   7   1.714286            171.4286
12  2  2   14     8   6   2.333333            233.3333
13  3  2   17    13   4   4.250000            425.0000
14  4  2   13     9   4   3.250000            325.0000
15  5  2    8     4   4   2.000000            200.0000
16  6  2    6     3   3   2.000000            200.0000
17  7  2    7     2   5   1.400000            140.0000
18  8  2   13    11   2   6.500000            650.0000
19  9  2   13     2  11   1.181818            118.1818
20 10  2   10     7   3   3.333333            333.3333
21  1  3   92    85   7  13.142857           1314.2857
22  2  3   85    79   6  14.166667           1416.6667
23  3  3  105   101   4  26.250000           2625.0000
24  4  3   92    88   4  23.000000           2300.0000
25  5  3   94    90   4  23.500000           2350.0000
26  6  3  101    98   3  33.666667           3366.6667
27  7  3  104    99   5  20.800000           2080.0000
28  8  3   95    93   2  47.500000           4750.0000
29  9  3  110    99  11  10.000000           1000.0000
30 10  3  118   115   3  39.333333           3933.3333

Using within, more concise but new columns are backwards ordered.
> df.test |> within({
+   delta <- sapply(unique(sc), FUN=\(x) {
+     vals[sc == x] - vals[sc == 1]
+   }) |> as.vector()
+   dif <- abs(delta - vals)
+   delta.perc <- abs(delta)/dif + 1
+   delta.perc.increase <- delta.perc*100
+ })
   cd sc vals delta delta.perc.increase delta.perc dif
1   1  1    7     0            100.0000   1.000000   7
2   2  1    6     0            100.0000   1.000000   6
3   3  1    4     0            100.0000   1.000000   4
4   4  1    4     0            100.0000   1.000000   4
5   5  1    4     0            100.0000   1.000000   4
6   6  1    3     0            100.0000   1.000000   3
7   7  1    5     0            100.0000   1.000000   5
8   8  1    2     0            100.0000   1.000000   2
9   9  1   11     0            100.0000   1.000000  11
10 10  1    3     0            100.0000   1.000000   3
11  1  2   12     5            171.4286   1.714286   7
12  2  2   14     8            233.3333   2.333333   6
13  3  2   17    13            425.0000   4.250000   4
14  4  2   13     9            325.0000   3.250000   4
15  5  2    8     4            200.0000   2.000000   4
16  6  2    6     3            200.0000   2.000000   3
17  7  2    7     2            140.0000   1.400000   5
18  8  2   13    11            650.0000   6.500000   2
19  9  2   13     2            118.1818   1.181818  11
20 10  2   10     7            333.3333   3.333333   3
21  1  3   92    85           1314.2857  13.142857   7
22  2  3   85    79           1416.6667  14.166667   6
23  3  3  105   101           2625.0000  26.250000   4
24  4  3   92    88           2300.0000  23.000000   4
25  5  3   94    90           2350.0000  23.500000   4
26  6  3  101    98           3366.6667  33.666667   3
27  7  3  104    99           2080.0000  20.800000   5
28  8  3   95    93           4750.0000  47.500000   2
29  9  3  110    99           1000.0000  10.000000  11
30 10  3  118   115           3933.3333  39.333333   3

